# VS Code "textSeparator.foreground" setting

Tags: visual-studio-code

What is the `textSeparator.foreground` color controlling? On https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color, it says "Color for text separators." If anyone can include a screenshot, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/26298), that's for the foreground color of text section separators, as seen in the attached picture:

[image: text separator foreground]

Comment: I don't understand. Are you referring to the `-`?

Comment: That should be the thin line dividing blocks of text

Comment: Hmm, I'm not seeing this in my editor - are you? Does it need to be turned-on...?